# Installing NPM package with Rust std::process::Command

Tags: rust, npm-install

I am trying to programmatically install an NPM package as part of a Rust program.

I am using the [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) struct, and can successfully run Node with:

```
pub fn check_for_node(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    println!("Node Version: ");
    let node = process::Command::new("node")
        .arg("-v")
        .status()?;

    self.node_is_installed = node.success();
    Ok(())
}
```

The code above returns:

```
Node Version:
v10.15.1
```

with no error.

However, when I run:

```
pub fn install_puppeteer(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    if self.node_is_installed {
        let npm = process::Command::new("npm")
            .arg("install")
            .arg("puppeteer")
            .status()?;
        self.puppeteer_is_installed = npm.success();
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I get the error:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the file specified." }', src\libcore\result.rs:999:5

If I run `npm -v` manually, I get `6.4.1` printed, so I know that NPM is installed.

Is there any reason that `std::process::Command` would work for Node and not for NPM, and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: `node` is an executable, `npm` is either a shell script or a batch file, depending on your OS - this has caused [issues with `Command` on Windows](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42791) before. Does it work if your `Command` launches `npm` through a call to `bash`/`cmd` instead of directly passing in `npm` as the command name?

Comment: in case it's not clear do `process::Command::new("bash")
            .arg("-c").arg("npm install puppeteer")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the working directory to `C:\Program Files\nodejs` prior to  to running the command with:

```rust
let npm = Path::new("C:\Program Files\nodejs");
assert!(env::set_current_dir(&npm).is_ok());
```

After changing the working directory to my Node install path, I was able to successfully run:

```rust
 let npm = process::Command::new("npm.cmd")
      .arg("install")
      .arg("-g")
      .arg("puppeteer")
      .status()?;
```

I am on Windows, but to make this answer cross platform the following code could be used:

```rust
#[cfg(windows)]
pub const NPM: &'static str = "npm.cmd";

#[cfg(not(windows))]
pub const NPM: &'static str = "npm";

...

 let npm = process::Command::new(NPM)
      .arg("install")
      .arg("-g")
      .arg("puppeteer")
      .status()?;
```